# Windows job scheduled through TWS gives MDAC error

Tags: tivoli, mdac

I have a job defined for a Windows FTA (TWS term).  This job calls a bat script.
When thte script is run from the command prompt on the windows box, it runs ok, but when it is scheduled through TWS it comes up with the errors:

Application started at 6/3/2014 10:00:16 PM

There is error in the file Field_Details.csv.Please check with the below error
The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later.

There is error in converting Field in Excel(Field_Details.csv) to list in program. Please Check with below error message
The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later.
Application ended at 6/3/2014 10:00:16 PM

This error is stopping the script from continuing.  I've seen some other posts about stopping and starting app pools on the windows box, but the box this is running on does not have an IIS Manager, so I don't know whaere to go from here.
ANy help is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

I work on TWS.  I had a very similar error message (MDAC) coming up on one of our FTAs.  There wasn't a fix per-se, but what was missing was that the file that TWS calls before the jobs starts, to check if there is a user-specific setup file to call was not checking for that file.  We set it to check and ultimately call the setup-file and everything was good.

The file which does the check is in the TWS install dir, named jobmanrc.cmd.  The scripting in that file checks to see if the (user-specific) setup file, djobmanrc.cmd exisits, if it does, it sources it to set up variables, etc.
I'd say check to see if your jobmanrc.cmd is checking for djobmanrc.cmd.